# React-Native: Problems with Axios on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using ReactNative keep getting a network error on every Axios Request on iOS.

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target-shim.js:818)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:574)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:388)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:501
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:436)
    at MessageQueue.js:111
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:384)
```

Apparently, iOS doesn't allow APIs that don't use HTTPS to run, but as per my research, updating Info.plist should have done the trick. Here's how I have updated it:

[image]

The android version of this application works perfectly fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was pretty simple. My server is hosted on `localhost`, and you need to use an IP/hostname that is not `127.0.0.1`/`localhost`. Find your private IP address and start your server on that and reference that in `react-native`. However, `127.0.0.1`/`localhost` works fine on Android.

A live server should work too as long as you use HTTPS or allow ignoring HTTPS in your `Info.plist` file available in your iOS project workspace.