# How to upload image with axios using form data in react-native

Tags: react-native, axios, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an image after an image capture in react native using axios and formData. I am using the `react-native-camera` package to capture the image.

I have checked the other similar answers but none of them are working.

These are the two methods that I tried but it's not working. I am getting **Error: Network Error** in the below method.

```
  let bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append(`q_image_${serial}`, {
    uri: 'file:///data/user/0/com.student/cache/Camera/b6217266-35d5-4a0c-b09e-0c9f12777194.jpg', 
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: 'someName',
  });
  
  const { data } = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${baseURL}/service.php`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' 
    },
    data: bodyFormData
  });

  console.log('UPLOAD', data);
```

[image]

I am getting Images not uploaded response from the server with the below method.

```
  let bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append(`q_image_${serial}`, 'file:///data/user/0/com.student/cache/Camera/b6217266-35d5-4a0c-b09e-0c9f12777194.jpg');
  
  const { data } = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${baseURL}/service.php`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' 
    },
    data: bodyFormData
  });

  console.log('UPLOAD', data);
```

The server is working fine. I am able to upload an image using postman.

[image]

Is this an issue of react-native-camera or formData or axios?

Edit: I found it. I am using react-native version 0.62.* and this is an open issue on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551).

Comment: Ciao, you checked that `bodyFormData` contains only the photo you want to send to server? Another question: error you got it's just `Error: Network Error`? No other infos available?

Comment: If this is still making a problem in postman then maybe your are sending params in a wrong way or a server issue.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar No in postman it's working fine. As you can see in the image I have attached.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Ciao, yea the bodyFormData contains the image and two other params and I am sending those correctly. Attached full network error image in the question.

Comment: Suspiciously similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359834; does that help?

Comment: @AndyTaton No that is for iOS but I am using on android. Also that guy is getting network error on every api call but I am getting only on this api call. Only image upload ain't working for me

Comment: This is an open issue of RN 0.62.* Posted the github link in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and currently this is an open issue of react-native. If anyone is facing the same and is on RN version 0.62.* then please follow the steps.

1. In `gradle.properties` change Flipper Version to 0.52.0

   ```
   FLIPPER_VERSION=0.52.0
   ```

For some reason I got a multi-dex error after this and if you are facing the same then:

2. In `app/build.gradle` add

   ```
   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
   ```
3. Add `multiDexEnabled true` in defaultConfig in `app/build.gradle`.

   ```
   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.packageName"
      minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
      targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ```